# Can i still gzip and cache files if i use dropbox as a cdn?

Tags: caching, gzip, cdn, dropbox

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I am wondering if I use dropbox sort of like a psuedo cdn, can i still gzip and cache the content coming from dropbox, this would be the javascript, stylesheet, and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only dropbox can Gzip their files. If you want to gzip them, you would need to process those files on the fly or host them in your server (LOL that doesn't help you at all).

It is an interesting idea though. Here is another person using dropbox to host wordpress files.
http://www.labnol.org/software/dropbox-cdn-for-wordpress/18266/

Comment: The end of the article states that dropbox automatically gzipped the javascript file. Thanks for the link.

Comment: As of Jul 2013, I tried various way but I cant get file (javascript or not) in gzipped format